# GLSL 2.0 Color and Texture

Tags: glsl, webgl

Hi i'm new to GLSL and i'm having a few problems.

I'm trying to create a pair of GLSL Shaders to either use color or texture but i must be doing something wrong.
The problem is that if set uUseTexture to 0 (which should indicate color) it doesn't work (object is not colored). I know the coloring code works separately, any hints why it does not work using the if statement?

Here is the code:

// Fragment

```
precision mediump float;

uniform int uUseTexture;
uniform sampler2D uSampler;

varying vec4 vColor;
varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

void main(void) {

    if(uUseTexture == 1) {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
    } else {
        gl_FragColor = vColor;
    }

}
```

// Vertex

```
attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
attribute vec4 aVertexColor;
attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;

uniform int uUseTexture;
uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
uniform mat4 uPMatrix;

varying vec4 vColor;
varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);

    if(uUseTexture == 1) {
        vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
    } else {
        vColor = aVertexColor;
    }
```

Comment: This `vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t)` should be `vTextureCoord.st`. You should look up how [swizzle masks](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Types#Swizzling) work in GLSL.

Comment: Do you mean that the same shader code works if you replace `if(uUseTexture == 1)` by `if (true)` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing springs to mind immediately glancing over your code, but I'd like to take a moment and point out that this use case can be covered without needing an if statement. For example, let's treat `uUseTexture` as a float instead of an int (you could cast it in the shader but this is more interesting):

// Vertex

```
attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
attribute vec4 aVertexColor;
attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;

uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
uniform mat4 uPMatrix;

varying vec4 vColor;
varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
    // It may actually be faster to just assign both of these anyway
    vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
    vColor = aVertexColor;
}
```

// Fragment

```
uniform float uUseTexture;
uniform sampler2D uSampler;

varying vec4 vColor;
varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

void main(void) {
    // vTextureCoord is already a vec2, BTW
    vec4 texColor = texture2D(uSampler, vTextureCoord) * uUseTexture;
    vec4 vertColor = vColor * (1.0 - uUseTexture); 
    gl_FragColor = texColor + vertColor;
}
```

Now uUseTexture simply acts as a modulator for how much of each color source you want to use. And it's more flexible in that you could set it to 0.5 and get half texture/half vertex color too!

The thing that may surprise you is that there's a good likelihood that this is what the shader compiler is doing behind the scenes anyway when you use an if statement like that. It's typically more efficient for the hardware that way.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, found the problem, nothing to do with the shaders, it turns out i was buffering the texture coordinates with item size 22 instead of 2... i need to sleep more :)

And thanks for the modulator hint, will try it out :)